# How to update data to database using controller in Laravel - Error Non-static method

Tags: php, database, laravel

So Im trying to submit the edited data back to the database using the controller, yet I am getting the error **"Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update() should not be called statically"** I think the code in the update function needs to be changed.

web.php file

```
Route::post('/my-updated-routes', 'MyroutesController@update');
```

controller

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    Myroutes::update([ //updateing to myroutes table
        'start' => $request->start,
        'end' => $request->end,
        'waypoints' => implode(",", $request->waypoints)
    ]);
    return redirect('/my-saved-routes');
}
```

show.blade.php

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('/my-updated-routes') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Start Point</label>
        <input type="text" id="start" name="start" class="form-control" value="{{ $myroute->start }}" required/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>End Point</label>
        <input type="text" id="end" name="end" class="form-control" value="{{ $myroute->end }}" required/>
    </div>

    <div>
    <label for="mode">Mode of Travel</label>
        <select id="mode" class="form-control" onchange="calculateAndDisplayRoute();">
          <option value="DRIVING" name="driving">Driving</option>
          <option value="WALKING" name="walking">Walking</option>
          <option value="BICYCLING" name="cycling">Cycling</option>
          <option value="TRANSIT" name="public-transport">Public Transport</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <p>Note: Public Transport is only available for start and end points.</p>


    <div id="dynamicInput" class="form-group">
        <label>Additional Destinations</label>
        <input type="text" name="waypoints" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" value="{{ $myroute->waypoints }}">
    </div>

    <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="+" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');" style="padding:0 10px;">               
    </br></br>
    <input type="button" id="calc-route" style="color:#2b2b2b" class="btn btn-light" value="Calculate Route"/>

    <input type="submit" id="update-route" class="btn btn-success" value="Update"/>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete"/>

</form> <!-- end of form -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly (statically) call `::update(..)` method on your models. You necessarily have to scope it with some query method. For example `Myroutes::where(some_column, someValue)->update(...)` will work.

I'm not sure why that is, but I assume it's a way to prevent people from mistakenly updating everything in a table.

If, however you do want to update all rows in a table, you could do something simple like `Myroutes::where(true, true)->update(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what do you exactly want to update in the controller?

the update method is none-static method And you can't call it with (::)"pamayim nikodatiyim". And it means you must get the row that you want to update from database and then call the update method.

to do that you have two ways:

by laravel model binding, you can read the docs here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters

Or you can just send the id of the row that you want to update, retrieve the data and then call the update method:

```
$data = YourModelName::whereId($request['row_id'])->first();

$data->update([ //updateing to myroutes table
        'start' => $request->start,
        'end' => $request->end,
        'waypoints' => implode(",", $request->waypoints)
        ]);
```

You can not update without specifying which row you want to update. it doesn't make any sense.