# How to update database fields using controller Laravel - No error message

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5

I am going round in circles trying to update data to the database, I finally have got rid of all the errors so now its correctly redirects with no error yet it isnt updating on the site or on the database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

web.php

```
Route::put('/my-saved-routes/{myroute_id}', 'MyroutesController@update');
```

MyroutesController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{    
     $Myroutes = Myroutes::find($id);
     $Myroutes->start = $request->input('start');
     $Myroutes->end = $request->input('end');
     $Myroutes->waypoints = $request->input('waypoints');

     $Myroutes->save();

     return redirect('/my-saved-routes');
}
```

show.blade.php

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                            <h2>Route {{ $myroute->myroute_id }}</h2>                               
                            <form method="put" action="/my-saved-routes">
                                {{ method_field('put') }}
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Start Point</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="start" name="start" class="form-control" value="{{ $myroute->start }}" required/>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>End Point</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="end" name="end" class="form-control" value="{{ $myroute->end }}" required/>
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                <label for="mode">Mode of Travel</label>
                                    <select id="mode" class="form-control" onchange="calculateAndDisplayRoute();">
                                      <option value="DRIVING" name="driving">Driving</option>
                                      <option value="WALKING" name="walking">Walking</option>
                                      <option value="BICYCLING" name="cycling">Cycling</option>
                                      <option value="TRANSIT" name="public-transport">Public Transport</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <p>Note: Public Transport is only available for start and end points.</p>


                                <div id="dynamicInput" class="form-group">
                                    <label>Additional Destinations</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="waypoints" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" value="{{ $myroute->waypoints }}">
                                </div>

                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="+" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');" style="padding:0 10px;">               
                                </br></br>
                                <input type="button" id="calc-route" style="color:#2b2b2b" class="btn btn-light" value="Calculate Route"/>

                                <input type="submit" id="update-route" class="btn btn-success" value="Update"/>
                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete"/>

                            </form> <!-- end of form -->
```

Myroutes.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Myroutes extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'myroute_id',
        'user_id',
        'start',
        'end',
        'waypoints'
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'myroute_id';

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update data to database using controller in Laravel - Error Non-static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051457/how-to-update-data-to-database-using-controller-in-laravel-error-non-static-me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like below

```
Myroutes::where('id', $id)
                ->update(['start' => $request->input('start'),
                         'end'=>$request->input('end'),
                         'waypoint'=>$request->input('waypoints')]
                        );
```

Comment: Error message **SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'waypoints' cannot be null (SQL: update `myroutes` set `start` = deee, `end` = d, `waypoints` = , `updated_at` = 2018-04-27 10:13:23 where `myroute_id` = 26)** How to change waypoints to allow it to save as null

Comment: That's a database schema issue. You need to create a migration that changes 'waypoints' to have the ->nullable() method passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

try to

```
<form method="put" action="/my-saved-routes">
```

update

```
<form method="post" action="/my-saved-routes/{{ $myroute->myroute_id }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="/my-saved-routes/{{ $$myroute->myroute_id) }}">
  {{ method_field('patch') }}
  {{ csrf_field() }}
```